# libssh2 remote ncurses application

Tags: c++, c, ncurses, libssh2

I'm in the initial stages of designing an app that will connect to a remote server via ssh using the libssh2 library. One of the features I would like to have is the ability to be able to interact with a remote ncurses application. I understand that when connecting with libssh2 and executing a command, I will be returned a string that represents the output of the command on the remote system. But what if that command launches an ncurses (graphical) application. What output would I get back?

Comment: Make a basic little application and test it to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as you're requesting a pty on the other end, your ncurses programs will be sending you lots of control sequences dictating cursor positions, colors, etc... What you're going to end up doing is writing a terminal emulator in order to interact with ncurses applications, so you might do some searching for vt100 terminal emulation or something of the sort.

Comment: Thanks. I already figured that's what I would have to do based on my research online but I was hoping that someone would know a way to avoid that.